# Button doesn't popup window. There is no reaction. No console errors

Tags: javascript, button

I created button in my project but it doesn't work.

Every Pokémon card will have a button- its function is to show popup window with additional information about a Pokémon, for now it will pop up only with  simple header.

```js
   const pokemonList = document.getElementById('pokemonList')
const loadMoreButton = document.getElementById('loadMoreButton')

const maxRecords = 151
const limit = 10
let offset = 0;
// This function takes a Pokemon object and converts it into an HTML list item (<li>) string representation. 
// It uses template literals to interpolate data from the Pokémon object into the HTML string. 
function convertPokemonToLi(pokemon) {
    return `   
    <li class="pokemon ${pokemon.type}">
            <span class="number">#${pokemon.number}</span>
            <span class="name">${pokemon.name}</span>

            <div class="detail">
                <ol class="types">
                    ${pokemon.types.map((type) => `<li class="type ${type}">${type}</li>`).join('')}
                    </ol>
                <button type="button" id="openPopupBtn"><img id="pokeball" src="/assets/img/pokeball.png" alt="Pokeball">Details</button>
                <div id="popupWindow" class="popup">
                    <div class="popup-content">
                        <span id="closePopupBtn" class="close-btn">&times;</span>
                        <h2>Hello! This is a Popup!</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>              
            <img src="${pokemon.photo}"
            alt="${pokemon.name}">
            </div>
    </li>
    `
}

// This function fetches Pokémon using the pokeApi.getPokemons 

function loadPokemonItens(offset, limit) {
    pokeApi.getPokemons(offset, limit).then((pokemons = []) => {
        const newHtml = pokemons.map(convertPokemonToLi).join('')
        pokemonList.innerHTML += newHtml
    })
        .then(() => {
            document.getElementById('openPopupBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                document.getElementById('popupWindow').style.display = 'block';
            })

            document.getElementById('closePopupBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                document.getElementById('popupWindow').style.display = 'none';
            })
        })
}

loadPokemonItens(offset, limit)

loadMoreButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    offset += limit
    const qtdRecordsWithNexPage = offset + limit

    if (qtdRecordsWithNexPage >= maxRecords) {
        const newLimit = maxRecords - offset
        loadPokemonItens(offset, newLimit)

        loadMoreButton.parentElement.removeChild(loadMoreButton)
    } else {
        loadPokemonItens(offset, limit)
    }
})
```

```css
#openPopupBtn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  padding: 0.15rem 0.2rem;
  margin: 0.15rem 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  color: white;
}
.popup {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  /* Black with opacity */
}

.popup-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f44336;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

PokeApi JavaScript:

```js
const pokeApi = {}
//This function transforms the detailed data fetched from the PokeAPI into a custom Pokemon object.
function convertPokeApiDetailToPokemon(pokeDetail) {
    const pokemon = new Pokemon()
    pokemon.number = pokeDetail.id
    pokemon.name = pokeDetail.name

    const types = pokeDetail.types.map((typeSlot) => typeSlot.type.name)
    const [type] = types

    pokemon.types = types
    pokemon.type = type

    pokemon.photo = pokeDetail.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default

    return pokemon
}
//This method fetches detailed data for a single Pokemon from the PokeAPI
pokeApi.getPokemonDetail = (pokemon) => {
    return fetch(pokemon.url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(convertPokeApiDetailToPokemon)
}
//This method fetches a list of Pokemons from the PokeAPI with pagination (using offset and limit parameters):
pokeApi.getPokemons = (offset = 0, limit = 10) => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`

    return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((jsonBody) => jsonBody.results)
        .then((pokemons) => pokemons.map(pokeApi.getPokemonDetail))
        .then((detailRequests) => Promise.all(detailRequests))
        .then((pokemonsDetails) => pokemonsDetails)
}
```

I tried different ways of placement a button  but nothing work. Button is just inactive. I made some logic mistake I suppose.

Comment: IDs must be **unique**

Comment: Your demo has two functions, but nothing ever calls them. I'm not sure what is supposed to happen here

Comment: As Quentin says, IDs must be unique in a page; so for example your `img id="pokeball"` and `div id="popupWindow"` & others will be a problem. But especially your `.getElementById("openPopupBtn").addEventListener("click",...` is going to keep getting the _same_ element and adding all of the event listeners to just that one element.

Comment: I've changed for unique IDs but still doesn't work. The buttons have zero reaction

Comment: Can you please create a proper [mre] we can verify? Right now, it only throws an error because `pokeApi` is not defined. So either add the necessary scripts for that, or provide the necessary data in static form.

Answer (score 0):

When you use document.getElementById('openPopupBtn'), its get the first element by id. Try to specify an id for each Pokémon cards

use querySelectorAll('penPopupBtn')

```
document.querySelectorAll('#openPopupBtn').forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
          btn.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
    })
})
```

Comment: I changed 'none' to block and buttons works! 
I tried analogy with closePopupBtn but it doesn't work window stay open.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).